# How to change title and labels for effects plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am using `library(effects)` to create predicted probabilities after running my model. Here's the code:

```
v1 <- rnorm(1:10)
v2 <- rnorm(1:10)
v3 <- rnorm(1:10)

mydf<- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)

mymodel <- lm(v1 ~ v2 + v3, data = mydf)
summary(mymodel)
plot(allEffects(mymodel))
```

Everything is fine and both plots are generated. However, I want to change the title and x labels. For instance, I want to have "first plot" as the title of my first plot and "second plot" as the title of my second plot. Also, want the x-axis of my first plot to be titled "variable 1" and the second plot " variable 2."

Answer (score 1):

For the x-axes labels, you can pass them in as a list; but you will need to connect the new names with the original ones from the model in the list call:

```
plot(allEffects(mymodel), xlab = list(v1 = "Variable 1", v2 = "Variable 2", v3 = "Variable 3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v1 <- rnorm(1:10)
v2 <- rnorm(1:10)
v3 <- rnorm(1:10)
    
mydf<- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)

mymodel <- lm(v1 ~ v2 + v3, data = mydf)
summary(mymodel)

all<-allEffects(mymodel)
p1<-plot(all,"v2" ,
    xlab =  "v2 (or other)", ylab= "v1 (or other)", 
         main="main1")
p2<-plot(all,"v3" ,
         xlab =  "v3 (or other)", ylab= "v1 (or other)", 
         main="main2")
    
# Load cowplot
library("cowplot")    
plot_grid(p1,p2)
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: You should explain what the code does, code only answers are not well seen.